# identify local notification in didReceiveLocalNotification methods

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have set the multiple notification in my app.

Now i want to identify which local notification called.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the local notification call this function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[notif userInfo]);
}
```

Firstly when you schedule LocalNotification then time you set dictionary in `userInfo`.

```
Example:-
localNotif.userInfo = dic;
```

In Userinfo dictionary you add one extra key . this you receive notification the time you identify which type local notification you get

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif 
    {
        f ([notif.userInfo valueForKey:@"Key 1"]==@"Object 1") {

            NSLog(@"This is notification 1");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify UILocalNotification,

You need to set the property of userinfo of UIlocalNtification. Using this value after in didRecieveNotification method you can identify which UILocalNotification is called